# Magit refs buffer no longer able to switch branches

Tags: key-bindings, magit

After last update, the `*magit-refs` buffer no longer switches to the branch under point when pressing <kbd>RET</kbd>, instead, it shows last commit from the branch I wanted to check out (completely useless behavior, at least for me). Is there any way to have <kbd>RET</kbd> work as it used to?

I figured I could do <kbd>b</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd>, to achieve the same effect, but I'm too used to <kbd>RET</kbd> working as it used to, and when accidentally I press it, Emacs hangs because the diff may be quite large.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As highlighted in the [release notes for version 2.9](https://emacsair.me/2016/12/07/magit-2.9/) (which explains at some length why this change was made):

> Please note that you can trivially revert this change locally, by adding `(setq magit-visit-ref-behavior '(checkout-any focus-on-ref))` to your init file.

If you're reverting to that behaviour, you may appreciate this safety-net for preventing accidental check-outs:

```el
;; I keep unintentionally checking out branches from the refs buffer.
(defadvice magit-visit-ref (around my-protect-accidental-checkout)
  "Protect against expensive accidental checkout of a reference."
  (if (derived-mode-p 'magit-refs-mode)
      (if (y-or-n-p "Checkout reference? ")
          ad-do-it
        (message "Aborted."))
    ad-do-it))
(ad-activate 'magit-visit-ref)
```

Comment: It's one of those imaginary "UX improvements"... I see not only in Magit, unfortunately... *sigh*. Have been using Magit for at least five years now, and not even once checked a branch I didn't intend to check.

Comment: I lost count of the number of times I did it before I wrote that particular advice -- and every single time was super-annoying. It's not an "imaginary" improvement; it's merely an example of the fact that Magit caters to a wide range of users, with a similarly wide range of habits and expectations, and it's impossible to please everyone (but I think tarsius does a fantastic job of pleasing as many people as possible, by implementing backwards-compatibility features like this one when changes are made).

Comment: Erm... no. Branch checkout is an asynchronous operation: you have all the tools you need to cancel it, if you think it's a wrong branch. Generating a diff isn't, so you are stuck until it ends.

Comment: I can only disagree about the relative severity of the two unintended actions (and I'm pretty sure you can `C-g` out of a magit diff generation) -- but I wasn't trying to argue that point, and really I feel it's probably just another example of differing use-cases.